# Structured data with syntax errors detected in Google console (Yoast script)

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console, yoast

I have got a simple WordPress website and just got this error on Google console:
To the owner of https://mywebsite.com/:

Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Unparsable structured data issues:

Top Errors

Errors can prevent your page or feature from appearing in search results. The following errors were found on your site:

Incorrect value type

We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.

I checked it on https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

and it seems it is part of Yoast plugin script. I know what sintax error but how can I change it?

{"@type":"WebPage","@id":"#webpage","url":!1,"name":"","isPartOf":{"@id":"https://mywebsite.com/#website"},"inLanguage":"en-US"}]}

I think getting rid of "!" will fix it but how to change this code?